# C programming : Moving average filter

Tags: c, matlab, filter

I have tried to implement an equivalent in C of the Matlab function smooth(y, span).
The Matlab code of the function is :

```
n = length(y);
span = min(span,n);
width = span-1+mod(span,2); % force it to be odd
c = filter(ones(width,1)/width,1,y);
cbegin = cumsum(y(1:width-2));
cbegin = cbegin(1:2:end)./(1:2:(width-2))';
cend = cumsum(y(n:-1:n-width+3));
cend = cend(end:-2:1)./(width-2:-2:1)';
c = [cbegin;c(width:end);cend];
```

And here is my C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// Compute cumulative sum of a signal of a given size.
void cumulative_sum(float *cum_vector, float *signal, int size)
{
    int i;
    cum_vector[0]=0;
    cum_vector[1]=signal[0];
    for(i=2;i<=size;i++)
    {
        cum_vector[i] = cum_vector[i-1] + signal[i-1];
    }
 }

 // Moving average filter of a signal of a given size with a pre-defined span.
 void moving_average(float *vector, int size, int span)
{
if (span > size)
{
    span = size; //span = min(span,size);
}
int i;
int j=0;
int width = span - 1 + (span % 2); //force it to be odd
float *cum_x_tmp;
cum_x_tmp = (float *)malloc(size*sizeof(float));
cumulative_sum(cum_x_tmp,vector,size);

for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    if (i< (width - 2)/2 +((width-2)%2 !=0))
    {
        vector[i] = cum_x_tmp[2*i+1]/(2*i+1);
    }
    else if (i>=(width - 2)/2 +((width-2)%2 !=0) && i<= (width - 2)/2 +((width-2)%2 !=0) + size - width)
    {
        int ind1 =i + floor(width/2)+1;
        int ind2 =i - floor(width/2)-1+1;
        vector[i] = (cum_x_tmp[ind1] - cum_x_tmp[ind2])/width;
    }
    else if (i>(width - 2)/2 +((width-2)%2 !=0) + size - width)
    {
        int ind4 = size-1-width+3-1+2*j+1;
        vector[i] = (cum_x_tmp[size] - cum_x_tmp[ind4])/(width -2*(j+1));
        j++;
    }
}
}int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

int N=900;
float data;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("file.txt","r");

float *signal;
signal = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));

int i;
for (i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    fscanf(fp, "%f", &data);
    signal[i]=data;
}
fclose(fp);

moving_average(signal,N,50);

free(signal);

return 0;}
```

I obtained the same values as the Matlab code until a certain index of the signal at which the code abords. Does anyone know why and how to fix it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `for(i=2;i<=size;i++)` is suspicious.  I'd expect `for(i=1;i<size;i++)`.

Comment: Yes indeed you're right it is the more logical. However, it is only a part of a bigger code and i needed the cumulative sum to be 0,signal[0],signal[1],... for another part!

Comment: "until a certain index of the signal at which the code abords." Please be more specific. Do you know at which index? That will narrow down in which of the cases within your loop the issue exists. I recommend that you run your program under Valgrind, it will point out if and where you access memory that doesn't belong to your program (which is the most likely cause of the crash).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to index `cum_vector[size]` in `cumulative_sum`, then you need to make sure that `cum_vector` has `size+1` elements. In your code it has only `size`. Thus, you are writing out of bounds, which is likely to cause a crash later on.

In `moving_average` you also access `cum_x_tmp[size]`.

Allocate your array as follows:

```
cum_x_tmp = (float *)malloc((size+1)*sizeof(float));
```

Running your program under Valgrind or a similar memory checker will point out this issue, as well as the memory leak pointed out in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a memory leak:

On each invocation of `moving_average`, you are leaking the memory allocated for `cum_x_tmp`:

```
    float *cum_x_tmp;    
    cum_x_tmp = (float *)malloc(size*sizeof(float));
```

You need to free that memory when you no longer need it.
Also, you should add a null-check to the value returned from [malloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), to detect when allocation fails. Otherwise, you'll invoke Undefined Behavior when deallocating the null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The original code cleaned up to actually compile and work correctly.  aka Matlab's smooth() function.  Post back if you see a way to make this faster and/or safer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void get_cum_sum(double *cum_vector, double *signal, int size)
{
   int i;
   cum_vector[0] = signal[0];
   for(i = 1; i < size; i++)
   {
      cum_vector[i] = signal[i] + cum_vector[i-1];
   }
}

void smooth(double *vector, int size, int span)
{
   int i, window, half_window, tmp_index;
   double *cum_x_tmp;

   if (span > size)
   {
      span = size;
   }
   window = span - 1 + (span % 2);
   half_window = window / 2;

   cum_x_tmp = (double *)malloc((size) * sizeof(double));

   get_cum_sum(cum_x_tmp, vector, size);

   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      if (i <= half_window)
      {
         vector[i] = (cum_x_tmp[2 * i]) / (2 * i + 1);
      }
      else if (i >= (size - half_window))
      {
         tmp_index = (size - (i + 1)) * 2 + 1;
         vector[i] = (cum_x_tmp[size - 1] - cum_x_tmp[i - (tmp_index / 2) - 1]) / tmp_index;
      }
      else
      {
         vector[i] = (cum_x_tmp[i + half_window] - cum_x_tmp[i - half_window - 1]) / window;
      }
   }
   free(cum_x_tmp);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   int i;
   int N = 7;
   double data;
   FILE *fp;
   double *signal;

   signal = (double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
   fp = fopen("data.txt","r");

   for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
      fscanf(fp, "%lf", &data);
      signal[i] = data;
   }

   fclose(fp);

   smooth(signal, N, 7);

   for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
      printf("signal[%d] = %f\n", i, signal[i]);
   }

   free(signal);

   return 0;
}
```